# How to sum each value of a column for different individuals in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

I have a little problem with a dataset.

My data look like this:

```
                   Volume       Pressure

Patient 1           31             15
                    34             35
                    32             44


Patient 2           34             23
                    23             23
                    23             24
```

I want to obtain a final output of a mean patient that has for each value of pressure and of volume the mean of the pressures/volumes of the two patients.

```
                   Volume      Pressure
Mean Patient     (31+34)/2     (15+23)/2
                 (34+23)/2     (35+23)/2
                 (32+23)/2     (44+24)/2
```

I have no idea how to write this rule, as I don't know how to explicit that I want to repeat this procedure for every patient I have (I have more than two).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: are you open to a helper column?

Comment: @ForwardEd definitely!

Comment: Wouldn't `Volume: = AVERAGE(all_volumes)` and `Pressure = AVERAGE(all_pressures)`?  Or must you have three different rows for the first, second and third readings? (Or is one cell with three lines in it?)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making it too difficult. Simply use `AVERAGE` and drag.

For example, `=AVERAGE(B7,B2)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IF you are open to a helper column you can use the following solution.

For the helper column you want to ad a test/sample ID.  To keep it simple I used a numbering system starting at 1 and increments by 1 for each successive test. Plae the following formula in a column adjacent to your first patient results and copy down.  You can hide this column later for presentation purposes or stick it off to the side if so desired

```
=IF(AND(A3="",B3=""),"",IF(AND(A3<>"",B3<>""),1,E2+1))
```

Then lets build a table of results.  Column 1 will be your test/sample ID.  Column 2 will be your mean volume, and column 3 will be your mean pressure.  In the first cell of column 2  place the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($E:$E,$G3,B:B)/COUNTIF($E:$E,$G3)
```

Copy this formula down as needed and one column to the right.

Update cell references to suit your needs.

Dont use full column reference if you have other information in the column either above or below your data range.

[image: POC]